# bar charts in ggplot2 with .csv files

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think my question is very basic, but I have just begun to learn R. Today I have spent a long time trying to import data from .csv files. I have 25 .csv files, which are all structured like the example file. From the data I would like to create graphs like I did with Excel [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahmjl.png), because with ggplot2 I can create much nicer graphs than with Excel.
In my csv files I have data from different organisms, the concentration of formed compounds (molecule1 and molecule2) and the standard deviation (molecule1sd, molecule2sd). In my figures I want to show the data for one compound with standard deviations for all organisms as a bar chart, which is overlaid with a line chart with the concentration without organisms.
However, somehow I can' t get this to work. I have tested this, but somehow it doesn' t work.
I need your help

```
 + usePackage("data.table")
> usePackage("ggplot2")
> 
> # load packages
> library(data.table)
> library(ggplot2)
> 
> results <- fread("Results.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
> 
> str(results)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  7 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Organism   : chr  "AC1432" "D3425" "BF3523" "XR2405" ...
 $ Molecule1  : num  39.5 418.4 189.2 49.3 4610.9 ...
 $ Molecule1sd: num  19.6 70.9 102.8 21.2 275.9 ...
 $ Molecule2  : num  276 6511 235 500 11205 ...
 $ Molecule2sd: num  21 291.1 109.7 67.1 94.5 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> 
> df <- data.frame(results)
> 
> str(df)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Organism   : chr  "AC1432" "D3425" "BF3523" "XR2405" ...
 $ Molecule1  : num  39.5 418.4 189.2 49.3 4610.9 ...
 $ Molecule1sd: num  19.6 70.9 102.8 21.2 275.9 ...
 $ Molecule2  : num  276 6511 235 500 11205 ...
 $ Molecule2sd: num  21 291.1 109.7 67.1 94.5 ...
> 
> ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Organism)+
+            geom_bar(aes(fill=Organism)) +   geom_errorbar(data=df, mapping=aes(x="Organism", ymin="Molecule1sd", ymax="Molecule1sd"), width=0.2, size=1, color="blue")
+
```

Data from results.csv in the following table:

```html
</head>

<body link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=480 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:360pt'>
 <col width=80 span=6 style='width:60pt'>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 width=80 style='height:15.0pt;width:60pt'>Organism</td>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'>Molecule1</td>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'>Molecule1sd</td>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'>Molecule2</td>
  <td colspan=2 width=160 style='mso-ignore:colspan;width:120pt'>Molecule2sd</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>AC1432</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>39.5</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>19.6</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>275.9</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>21.0</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>D3425</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>418.4</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>70.9</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>6511.0</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>291.1</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>BF3523</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>189.2</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>102.8</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>235.2</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>109.7</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>XR2405</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>49.3</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>21.2</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>499.9</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>67.1</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>XR2463</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>4610.9</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>275.9</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>11205.3</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>94.5</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>ATF259</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>751.7</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>71.6</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>9507.9</td>
  <td class=xl65 align=right>707.2</td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>without organism</td>
  <td align=right>35</td>
  <td></td>
  <td align=right>250</td>
  <td colspan=2 style='mso-ignore:colspan'></td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'></td>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'></td>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'></td>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'></td>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'></td>
  <td width=80 style='width:60pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I can’t get it to work is not a descriptive question.  A couple of suggestions.  In your ggplot definition, I believe you want a “geom_col” chart and not a _bar.  Also you need to define “y= ...” inside the “aes( )”.

Comment: i tried this (but it doesn´t work):     p= ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Organism, y="Molecule1")+
+               geom_col(aes(fill=Organism)) +   geom_errorbar(data=df, mapping=aes(x="Organism", ymin="Molecule1sd", ymax="Molecule1sd"), width=0.2, size=1, color="blue")
+           
+           ggsave("results.png", plot=p, width=7.5, height=2.5, dpi=150)

Comment: You have an extra `+`  before `geom_col`, and `ggsave` should stand alone.
EDIT: Here I am talking about your comment above, not your question.

Comment: now i have got my first diagram, and I can save it :) but all columns have the same size :(             > p= ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Organism))+
+               geom_col(data=df, aes(y="Molecule1"))
>                        
>           
> p
> ggsave("results.png", plot=p, width=7.5, height=2.5, dpi=150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a starting point:

```
ggplot( df ,aes( Organism, Molecule1, fill=Organism )) +
    geom_bar( stat="identity" ) +
    geom_errorbar( aes(ymin=Molecule1-Molecule1sd, ymax=Molecule1+Molecule1sd), width=.2 )
```

Changing the details can be done later easily, once you have a working backbone.

Saving can be done outside of ggplot, simply by calling:

```
png("yourfile.png")
<plotting stuff>
dev.off()
```

Result:

[image: ggplot2 starting point]